# Matplotlib-cpp : ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, cmake

I am trying to use [matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp) for a C++ project compiled by Visual Studio using CMake.

The python distribution I use is Anaconda2 (latest 2.7 version downloaded today). I removed every other python distribution that was on my computer.

I added the paths to the Anaconda2 folder to the system AND user environment variables. (C:\Anaconda2...)

CMake is finding it correctly as when configuring the project with CMake, I have:

```
Found PythonInterp: C:/Anaconda2/python.exe (found suitable version "2.7.16", minimum required is "2.7") 
Found PythonLibs: C:/Anaconda2/libs/python27.lib (found suitable version "2.7.16", minimum required is "2.7")
```

The project builds correctly with VS (no build or link error) but when I run a quick hello world, I have an error :

```
Hello World!
ImportError: No module named site
```

**This is the main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    plt::plot({ 1,3,2,4 });
    plt::show();

    return 0;
}
```

**This is the CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(PLT)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS            "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")

# main app
add_executable(
    plt
    src/main.cpp
)


# Matplotlib
find_package(PythonInterp   2.7     REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs     2.7     REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(plt ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

I read on this forum that this might be caused by some Path issues, but the path to python directories is set:

[image]

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 to build with CMake's "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" generator and I run my program through "cmd" and I think the problem is configuring the default python used by "cmd".

I precise that I tried matplotlib on Anaconda Python's prompt and it is working.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually occurs when the PYTHONHOME path is invalid or not set
try:

```
set PYTHONHOME=C:\Python27
```

Comment: In my case it is : C:/Anaconda2/ but this solved it
Thank you